# Campsite in Zugspitze area

Tags: germany, alps

Are there campsites in Zugspitze neighborhood?

I am asking about a place where a person can bring its own tent and stay in it for a night and pay not much for that. There is no need for saunas, pools and so on. All facilities that are required are bathroom and shower room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is one campsite in Grainau on the German side:

http://www.pure-camping.de/

And one in Ehrwald on the Austrian side:

http://www.campingehrwald.at/

Neither are particularly cheap, though (around 15 EUR per night for one person with a tent). The area is generally rather pricy.

Comment: I was afraid that there are no cheaper campsites. Thank you.